# Javascript: Calculation of the amount when changing the value of the third input

Tags: javascript

I have three fields that are calculated: coef, cost of materials, and manufacturing cost.

First, calculate its coef * cost of materials, result in manufacturing cost input.

The calculation of the total amount is the cost of materials * manufacturing cost, but I need the ability to change the amount of Manufacturing cost and get the total result

How to do this?

My code:

```js
function sum(el) {
  let coefEl = document.getElementById('coef');
  let entrPriceEl = document.getElementById('enterence_price');
  let extraEl = document.getElementById('extra');
  let priceEl = document.getElementById('price');
  let extraresultEl;
  let result;
  if (el.id === "enterence_price" || el.id === "extra" || el.id === "coef") {
    extraextraresultEl = parseFloat(coefEl.value) * parseFloat(entrPriceEl.value);
    extraEl.value = extraextraresultEl;
    result = (parseFloat(entrPriceEl.value) * parseFloat(coefEl.value) + parseFloat(extraEl.value));
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
      priceEl.value = result.toFixed(2);
    }
  } else if (el.id === "enterence_price" || el.id === "extra" || el.id === "coef") {
    result = parseFloat(entrPriceEl.value) * parseFloat(extraEl.value);
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
      priceEl.value = result;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<label>Coefficient<br></label>
<input type="text" value="2" id="coef" onkeyup="sum(this);">
<br>
<label>The cost of materials<br></label>
<input type="text" value="2000" id="enterence_price" onkeyup="sum(this);">
<br>
<label>Manufacturing cost<br></label>
<input type="text" id="extra" onkeyup="sum(this);">
<br>

<label>Sum<br></label>
<input type="text" id="price" onkeyup="sum(this);">
<br>
```

Comment: so you just want to manually edit the manufacturing cost, thats clear, but what will be the some? sum of all above fields?

Comment: The formula should work during editing: sum = (coefficient * The cost of material) + Manufacturing cost

Comment: in this case you need to call a diff function on mf. cost input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply a different function on mf cost input, because if you will use the same function, it will never let you alter the value, because its value also getting generated from the same function you write for above 2 values

if you need something else, pls feel free to comment

```js
let coefEl = document.getElementById('coef');
  let entrPriceEl = document.getElementById('enterence_price');
  let extraEl = document.getElementById('extra');
  let priceEl = document.getElementById('price');
function sum(el) {
  
  let extraresultEl;
  if (el.id === "enterence_price" || el.id === "extra" || el.id === "coef") {
    extraextraresultEl = parseFloat(coefEl.value) * parseFloat(entrPriceEl.value);
    extraEl.value = extraextraresultEl;
    result = (parseFloat(entrPriceEl.value) * parseFloat(coefEl.value) + parseFloat(extraEl.value));
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
      priceEl.value = result.toFixed(2);
    }
  } else if (el.id === "enterence_price" || el.id === "extra" || el.id === "coef") {
    result = parseFloat(entrPriceEl.value) * parseFloat(extraEl.value);
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
      priceEl.value = result;
    }
  }
}

function canBeChnaged(el){
  var coefVal = parseInt(coefEl.value);
  var costofMatVal = parseInt(entrPriceEl.value);
  var mfCostVal = parseInt(extraEl.value);
  var finalSum = (coefVal * costofMatVal) + mfCostVal;
  priceEl.value = finalSum.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<label>Coefficient<br></label>
<input type="text" value="2" id="coef" onkeyup="sum(this);">
<br>
<label>The cost of materials<br></label>
<input type="text" value="2000" id="enterence_price" onkeyup="sum(this);">
<br>
<label>Manufacturing cost<br></label>
<input type="text" id="extra" onkeyup="canBeChnaged(this);">
<br>

<label>Sum<br></label>
<input type="text" id="price" onkeyup="sum(this);">
<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

A more succinct way is to is to wrap everything into a `<form>` then listen for the `input` event. The `input` event will trigger a call to an event handler (in the example below it is `function calc(e)`) whenever the user enters data in a form control (in this case all `<input>`s of `<form>`). Use properties of HTML elements like `type` and `step` to control and validate user input. References to previously mentioned topics are located after the example below.

*Details are commented in example below*

```js
// Register the <form>
const form = document.forms[0];
// Register all form controls of <form>
// In this case all <input> and <output>
const data = form.elements;

// Run function calc() if any valid user input is entered in <form>
form.oninput = calc;

// Pass the event
function calc(e) {
  // Convert any valid user input of the <input>s into a real number
  const c = parseFloat(data.cof.value);
  const m = parseFloat(data.mat.value);
  const l = parseFloat(data.lab.value);
  // Reference the <output>
  const s = data.sum;
  // Realistic formula 
  const t = (c * m) + l;
  // Display the value of output as the result of formula
  s.value = t.toFixed(2);
}
```

```css
:root,
input,
output {
  font: 400 6vh/10vh Consolas;
}

label,
input,
output {
  display: inline-block;
}

label {
  width: 9ch;
}

input,
output {
  height: 1.5ch;
  width: 12ch;
  text-align: right;
}

#cof {
  width: 6ch;
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
 }
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Markup</label>
  <input id="cof" type="number" value="2">
  <br>
  <label>Materials</label>
  <input id='mat' type="number" value="0.00" step=".01">
  <br>
  <label>Labor</label>
  <input id='lab' type="number" value='0.00' step=".01">
  <hr>
  <label>Total: </label>
  <output id='sum'>0.00</output>
</form>
```

**Reference**

[**HTMLFormControlCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection)
[**HTMLFormElement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement)
[**`<input>` Element**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)